# Slide out old route and slide in newroute with Framer Motion in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, animation, next.js, framer-motion

So I'm playing around with Framer Motion and NextJS and I stumbled upon something which I want to achieve so that I can learn entry and exit animation.

I have two routes and when I click on a route I want the old route to slide out and the new route to slide in. Right now all the routes slide in. I tried using exit animation with values from initial animation but it is not working.

Here's the code:

_app.js:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
        <AnimatePresence>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </AnimatePresence>
    )
}
```

Animation:

```
const slide = {
    hidden: {
        y: '-100%',
        opacity: 0,
    },
    visible: {
        y: 0,
        opacity: 1
    }
}
```

Home Comp:

```
const Home = () =>{
      return (
           <motion.div initial='hidden' animate='visible' exit='hidden' variants={slide}>
                  Home Component
           </motion.div>
      )
}
```

About Comp:

```
const About = () =>{
      return (
           <motion.div initial='hidden' animate='visible' exit='hidden' variants={slide}>
                  About Component
           </motion.div>
      )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://www.framer.com/docs/animate-presence/#%23unmount-animations):

> Child `motion` components must each have a unique `key` prop so
> `AnimatePresence` can track their presence in the tree.

Comment: I just tried adding ```key={router.route}``` in each of those divs. Still the same.

Comment: Also tried wrapping Home and About component with AnimatePresence with attr exitBeforeEnter. Not working. :(

Comment: Wouldn’t that route change before you want the animation to trigger though? Try `key=“home”` and `key=“about”`.